# MySQL doesn't match varchar keys ending with a number

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I've defined a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `identifier` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `f1` char(1) NOT NULL,
  KEY `identifier` (`identifier`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and then added primary key and index as

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `identifier` ) 
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD INDEX ( `identifier` )
```

In the identifier field my table is populated with values like (about 800,000 records)

```
USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10172
USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-1020
USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10245
USER02-TEST-003-SUBA
USER02-TEST-002-SUBB
```

I've discovered that queries where the identifier ends with a number aren't matched:

```
SELECT *
FROM identifier
WHERE identifier = 'USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10245';
```

but queries matching an identifier which ends with letters are matched successfully

```
SELECT *
FROM identifier
WHERE identifier = 'USER02-TEST-003-SUBA';
```

My queries are exact, I don't need to compare with LIKE because my users provide me exact strings. Besides varchar(45) is more than enough space for my identifiers. 
What I did wrong? What could be the reason or solution?

Comment: Not related to the question, but you do not need to add index on identifier, since the primary key is already an index. Try running optimize table and retest.

Comment: Make sure that there are no hidden character at the end of the string behind your identifier. (line-breaks of other things). Did you add manually a string with numbers at the end? (I tested it, it works)

Comment: I have tested this and also works for me.

Comment: @user869097 the command is `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename`

Comment: Try this: `SELECT identifier, LENGTH(identifier) FROM mytable WHERE identifier LIKE 'USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10245%' AND LENGTH(identifier)>LENGTH('USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10245');` to check if there are trailing whitespace characters (as @Patrick suggested).

Comment: The loading from CSV may have left TABs or line-breaks or spaces.

Comment: Listen to ypercube's suggestions, and also do this: `select hex(identifier), concat('[', identifier, ']')` to get a good look at exactly what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made a typo in both the queries. Your table name should be mytable instead of identifier.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE identifier = 'USER01-TESTXXY-CAD-10245';
```

Is it a typo ?
Is there another table in your database that is called as identifier?